# How can check UV problem?

Tags: uv

I am new in **Blender,**

How can I understand normal of UV are correct or not?
In maya, we can understand, by color either UV is correct or not but in blender I didn't find any tool,

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What is correct/incorrect about the shown examples? Rotated UV island by 180 degrees?

Answer (score 1):

While UVs are seldom "right" or "wrong" you can visualize distortion compared to 3D model geometry by enabling "Stretch" in the UV editor Properties panel under Display:

[image: Visualize UV stretch]

With hard surface modeling this makes the out of place vertices pop but the biggest usage is perhaps with organic modeling where you have complex unwrap shapes and you want to tweak out the hard to spot local stretches.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be missing in the Blender, there are several useful plugins for UV maping, you may search for Blender UV add ons